# Initializing a Class - Unresolved External Symbol

Tags: c++, qt, class

I'm having trouble initializing classes, and all the results my searching finds is various other problems.

I am trying to initialize the class with `InkSpot *ink;` in the header file, then when the class needs to initialize I'm doing it with `ink = new InkSpot(this);` <- this line causes the error.

`inkpuppet.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl InkSpot::InkSpot(class QWidget *)" (??0InkSpot@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl InkPuppet::testButton(void)" (?testButton@InkPuppet@@AEAAXXZ)`

I am new to C++ and am having trouble solving classes. Here is my code.

inkpuppet.cpp

```
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"
#include "newdialog.h"
#include "inkspot.h"

#include <Qt>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QMainWindow>


InkPuppet::InkPuppet(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::InkPuppet)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    //connect the frame range boxes to the timeslider
    connect(ui->lowerFrameBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setMinimum(int)));
    connect(ui->upperFrameBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), this, SLOT(setMaximum(int)));

    //connect the menu items
    connect(ui->actionNew, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(actionNew()));

    //connect test
    connect(ui->testButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(testButton()));


}

InkPuppet::~InkPuppet()
{
    delete ui;
}

void InkPuppet::setMinimum(int value)
{
    ui->timeSlider->setMinimum(value);
}

void InkPuppet::setMaximum(int value)
{
    ui->timeSlider->setMaximum(value);
}

void InkPuppet::actionNew()
{
    NewDialog *dialog = new NewDialog;
    dialog->setModal(true);
    dialog->show();
}

void InkPuppet::testButton()
{
    ink = new InkSpot(this);
    ui->testButton->setText("working");
    //ui->paintAreaLayout->addWidget(ink->widget);
    //QWidget *widg = new QWidget();
    ui->paintAreaLayout->addWidget(ink->widget);

}
```

inkpuppet.h

```
#ifndef INKPUPPET_H
#define INKPUPPET_H

#include "inkspot.h"
#include "ink.h"

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QWidget>

namespace Ui {
class InkPuppet;
}

class InkPuppet : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit InkPuppet(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~InkPuppet();
    InkSpot *ink;

private slots:
    void setMinimum(int value);
    void setMaximum(int value);
    void actionNew();
    void testButton();

public:
    Ui::InkPuppet *ui;
};

#endif // INKPUPPET_H
```

inkspot.cpp

```
#include "inkspot.h"
#include "inkpuppet.h"
#include "ui_inkpuppet.h"

#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>


void InkSpot::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QFile *brushInput; //takes raw 8 bit grayscale image, 8 bit values only
    char *brushProto;
    uchar *brushData;

    brushInput = new QFile("x:\\Development\\InkPuppet\\brush.raw"); //open the raw file
    brushInput->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QDataStream in;
    in.setDevice(brushInput);
    int size = brushInput->size(); //set size to length of raw file

    brushProto = new char[size];
    in.readRawData(brushProto, size); //read file into prototype
    brushData = new uchar[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        brushData[i] = (uchar)brushProto[i]; //copy char to uchar array
    }

    QImage test(brushData, 128, 128, QImage::Format_Indexed8);
    QImage test2(128, 128, QImage::Format_ARGB32);

    QVector<QRgb> vectorColors(256); //create color table
    for(int c = 0; c < 256; c++)
    {
        vectorColors[c] = qRgb(c, c, c);
    }

    test.setColorTable(vectorColors);

    for(int iX = 0; iX < 100; ++iX)
    {
        for(int iY = 0; iY < 100; ++iY)
        {
            test2.setPixel(iX, iY, qRgba(255 - (qrand() % 100), 0 + (qrand() % 100), 0 + (qrand() % 100), qAbs((int)test.pixel(iX, iY)-255)));
        }
    }

    //final conversion for stencil and color brush
    QPixmap testPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(test2);
    QPixmap testPixmap2 = QPixmap::fromImage(test);

    QPainter painter(this);

    painter.drawPixmap(150, 50, 100, 100, testPixmap);
    painter.drawPixmap(50, 50, 100, 100, testPixmap2);

    delete[] brushProto;
    delete[] brushData;
    delete brushInput;
}
```

inkspot.h

```
#ifndef INKSPOT_H
#define INKSPOT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPaintEvent>
#include <QLabel>

namespace Ui {
class InkSpot;
}

class InkSpot : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit InkSpot(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~InkSpot();
    void draw(QPainter *painter);
    QWidget *widget;
    QLabel *label;
signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event);

private:
    Ui::InkSpot *ui;

};

#endif // INKSPOT_H
```

Comment: It looks like you are missing the definition for `explicit InkSpot(QWidget *parent = 0);`

Comment: It'll be easier for us to help you find the problem if you remove code that doesn't help in reproducing the error. for example, you could probably remove all that slot setup code. Delete as much as possible while still reproducing the original error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm looking through all the code you've posted for a definition of `InkSpot::InkSpot(QWidget *parent)` and I'm not seeing it. The error message is telling you that you haven't defined it. So I think that must be the problem.

It's not enough to put the *declaration* for a something in a header file, somewhere you must also *define* it. You did this with `InkPuppet::InkPuppet(QWidget *parent)`, so you just need to do the same with `InkSpot::InkSpot(QWidget *parent)`.

Comment: Still getting a similar error: `inkspot.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl InkSpot::~InkSpot(void)" (??1InkSpot@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl InkSpot::scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GInkSpot@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)`

Comment: OK, now the error is telling you haven't defined the destructor, so do that, or remove the destructor declaration from the header. Did you have a good reason for having a destructor? If not then get rid of it.

Comment: @user1090427 you might start to see a pattern here.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have done the trick, so I learned something here today. Unfortunately when I do: `ink = new InkSpot(this);` / `ui->paintAreaLayout->addWidget(ink->widget);` the program crashes.. not even sure where to start with fixing that.

Comment: Undoubtedly that's a whole different problem. Learn how to use your debugger is probably the best advice.